# Maquetado HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

tengo una duda. Ando maquetando una página para practicar html y css como parte de un ejercicio y llegué a una parte donde no se me ocurre como proceder.

Adjunto imagen de lo que se supone que debo replicar en la maquetación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que son 3 section mas o menos, con listas y divs para dar formato. ¿Pero como hago para poner los 3 sections con en esa imagen de fondo y hacer los iconos que se muestran a la derecha?

Comment: Creo que Flexbox o CSS Grid pueden ser muy utiles para esto... Has escrito algo de codigo? Lo mejor seria que primero intentes construir algo por tu cuenta y luego podemos ayudarte; mas un si estas en proceso de aprender

Comment: No tengo el codigo de esta parte, pero si tengo el codigo del resto de la maquetacion que ando haciendo (un profile, un menu y unos botones superiores). Intentaré hacerlo con el flexbox o el css grid y ver los resultados, si me atoro o algo volveré a preguntar. Más que nada esa era mi duda, que herramientas podría utilizar para atacar ese problema.

Comment: Puse abajo como respuesta un bosquejo de todo el esqueleto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En una maquetación es más complejo, es un poco tardío.
¿Tienes la imagen de fondo?

```
.body {
   background-image: url("urlImagen");
}
.disp-flex {
   display: inline-flex;
}
.secction1, .secction2, .secction3 {
   width: 20%;
}
```

En el HTML es simple.

```
<section class="container">
  <section class="disp-flex">
    <section class="secction1">
     <!--Aquí pones el código que debe ser en la primera parte.-->
    </section>
    <section class="secction2">
     <!--Aquí pones el código que debe ser en la segunda parte.-->
    </section>
    <section class="secction3">
     <!--Aquí pones el código que debe ser en la tercera parte.-->
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```